# Adjust arrow direction for UIActionsheet in iPad app

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet, ipad

Actually i have to display actionsheet with up and down arrow only. i have different columns in my view. now problem is that when i click on first column it displays actionsheet with up direction but middel of actionsheet and its indicate second column so i need to move arrow on left side.

i manage this things from below code. but i am not able to move arrow on right side for last column.

```
float x=offset.x;
float y=offset.y;
float w=newPop.frame.size.width;
float h=newPop.frame.size.height;
if(offset.x < 150)
{
    x = 160;
    w = w-180;
}
else if(offset.x > 600)
{
     x= 600;
   //w= w+180;
}

CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);


[newPop showFromRect:myImageRect inView:_calDay animated:YES];
```

i managed arrow's up-left direction by decreasing its width. but not able to adjust it up-right direction with that.

Let me know if you have any solution for this. Please check below snap that i manage up and left direction but i need up and right direction.

[image]

Comment: UIActionSheet? Not UIPopOverController?

Comment: yes i am displaying UIActionsheet with new API available from 3.2 showFromRect to display actiosheet look lik a popover.

Answer (score 1):

what i suggest is take one view with your actionsheet in it.
load that view in popover like this ....

```
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self.view];


if(popoverController)
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

popOverController *obj_popOverController = [[popOverController alloc] initWithNibName:@"popOverController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj_popOverController];
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 320.0)];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(p.x, p.y, 10, 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown  animated:YES];
[navController release];
```